# Is it possible to forbid ignoring Task returned by method in C#?

Tags: c#, return, async-await, task

My assumption (based on my current project) is that in 99% of cases if the return type of method is *Task*, then you do not want the return value to be ignored. This is especially a problem in case when method return type is changed from *void* to *Task*, because the execution flow may get obscured. I would really like to have error/warning in case that happens. I know compiler emits warning if this happens inside method marked async, but my statistics goes beyond async methods.

Is there a way to get such check? Perhaps with Roslyn it is possible to extend the compiler somehow?

Comment: You can find tools that do this for you. But perhaps a good way to learn and end up with exactly what you want is to write your own [Roslyn code analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx). These either install into your VS and apply to all your projects, or install into one of your projects (and are thus portable).

Comment: Crudely speaking, there is no "return value" with the return type is `Task`. However, you want to return `Task` in your async methods so that thrown exceptions can be caught. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: You're looking for the `Roslyn` code async / await analyzer. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03448836-db42-46b3-a5c7-5fc5d36a8308

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to get such check?

Yes, use the [`AsyncFixer`](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03448836-db42-46b3-a5c7-5fc5d36a8308). This is a **Roslyn** code analyzer that will work exactly as you desire. This will have warnings and allow you to fix all possible occurrences of the issue.